# this behaving unexpectedly in javascript

Tags: javascript

Practicing js on how functions work and how context changes for `this` keyword when used in different places.

Example below prints a object.

```
var a = {
        name:"test",
        fn:function(){
           console.log(this); 
        }
a.fn();
```

But when I run following code this is not

```
var a = {
        name:"test",
        fn:function(){ 
            var fn1 = function(){
               console.log(this);
            }
           fn1 ();
        }
a.fn();
```

it prints `Global execution context` why? Shouldn't it be either printing `fn` context or `a's` context?

Comment: `this` context in second snippet is related to `fn1`

Comment: but it prints global context or window object.

Comment: You *call* `fn1` as just `fn1()`. That's what makes `this` inside it undefined/`window`. Because there's no `<obj>.` before `fn1()`.

Comment: @Grafi What does *"related to `fn1`"* mean exactly?

Comment: @deceze `this` in second snippet is a reference to `fn1` context, not the container object. Hope this makes sense in english

Comment: @Grafi Yeah, no, that's not correct.

Comment: @deceze is it because it is not `strict`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context

Comment: @Grafi No, simply because that's not [how `this` works.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/476)